# "These are the strongest painkillers THERE ARE." or "These are strongest painkillers OUT THERE"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

In a medical text I came across the following sentence:

> Morphine and morphine-like drugs are the strongest painkillers **there are**.

I have never seen the usage of **"there are"** at the end of the sentence. So it sounded different and I can't make sure if it is all right to use it that way.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it correct to put **"there are"** at the end of the sentence like that?
2. Instead of a **"...there are."** structure at the end of the sentence, can I use **"...out there."**

Comment: **There are** would include drugs not available on the market, possibly experimental or confined to laboratories. **Out there** carries the sense of **available to purchase** or **on the market**.

Answer (score 2):

Both are perfectly correct and common. Here are some similar examples:

> Love is the strongest force there is.

> Billy the Kid is the cruelest outlaw there's ever been.

> IKEA has the best ratio of hot dog price to hot dog quality out there.

I think I perceive two subtle distinctions in usage, however.

- "out there" seems slightly less formal; "there is" and other conjugations is a little more poetic. But both suit a variety of contexts.
- "out there" suggests to me a more strict comparison, the results of a survey or contest or something. It would sound a little humorous or cutesy in the sentence about love.